# rel="prefetch" functionality for safari and mobile safari

Tags: ios, web, safari, prefetch, rel

Is there any known workaround that gives same functionality,  as rel="prefetch" for Safari and mobile Safari?

Comment: I would really love to know answer to this question. Its been 6 years and there is no prefetch in Safari?